# 3D animated movie about girl who travels to spirit realm

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a Japanese or Japanese-based animated film from around 2010-ish, maybe earlier. I can't remember if there was any talking in it (might have been a silent). It follows a girl who is either living at or visiting a relative (maybe a grandma) and finds a portal to a spirit realm via a well or pond. Upon entering, she finds a world full of anthropomorphized animals, in particular a rabbit that gives her a mask to disguise herself from evil spirits that inhabit the land (humans are not allowed). There is a train in there, I think, or some other method of transportation that keeps the girl safe from the spirits. In the end, the girl is detected by the spirits, and is forced to escape back to the human realm. The rabbit in the end, if I remember correctly, destroys the portal in the end, forever sealing off the two different realms.

Sorry for the rough and possibly inaccurate description, but I hope this is enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be *[Oblivion Island: Haruka and the Magic Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivion_Island:_Haruka_and_the_Magic_Mirror)*? Released in 2009 Japan, the 3D animated film follows the story of a girl, Haruka, who after falling into a mysterious pool in the woods, befriends a rabbit/fox hybrid who then helps her into disguise; it's a mask resembling a rabbit, in order to blend in.

### Trailer

Comment: Yes, matches several points, nice find:
"portal to a spirit realm via a well or pond" -- As can be seen in the trailer;

"mask to disguise herself ...  (humans are not allowed)" -- spot on;

"There is a train in there, ..." -- Indeed Haruka once travels with a train in the spirit world;

Comment: Yes, this is the one. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll have to check this one out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reasonably sure you're conflating two films by the [same studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studio_Ghibli#Feature_films)

- [*My Neighbour Totoro*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Neighbor_Totoro) (in which a a little girl chases a rabbit into a portal and ends up in a magical world)  
   
  and
- [*Spirited Away*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirited_Away) (in which a little girl covers her mouth to fit in with a spirit procession, extensive train scene, etc)

---

Comment: Neither of those are 3D though.

Comment: No, I remember these two movies. Neither of these are it, and there was a rabbit as the girls companion, which was smaller than her.

Comment: I enjoy both.. but, re: "in which a little girl wears a mask to fit in with spirits"  I don't recall Chihiro / Sen using a mask ever. She gets a job, early on, to be allowed to stay, but never really disguises herself -- the closest is walking closely with Haku so that they don't notice her.

Comment: @RazarMackham - At the start of Totoro, she encounters a [rabbit-sized rabbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx2e3.jpg)

Comment: @Jenayah - Both are 2.5D throughout, with elements of 3D.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out this exact same movie and stumbled upon this post.

Well… it finally came to me and hope this helps you…. “Over The Moon”

:)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct movie, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the OP already marked [Sunny's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/251932/122024) as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as denoted by the green tick next to it. This means that the OP believes that answer correctly identified the movie they were looking for.